# Datatables filter not showing when adding rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am struggling to find out how to solve an issue I have with the dataTable plugin.

I have an empty dataTable table with no records and a form which interacts with the database and adds results to this table dinamically by using the **fnAddData** function :

```
$.each( $.parseJSON(data), function(k, d){
    $('.table').dataTable().fnAddData([d.title,d.description]);
});
```

It works perfectly, adding the rows dinamically but when I reach the 10th result, it just displays 10 results (**"iDisplayLength": 50**) and pagination doesn't come up. The ajax json result returns more than 10 results, so they should appear.

I tried to redraw the table but this pagination doesn't work. If I refresh the page, it displays the pagination and the filter field, so I was wondering if there is any way to display the filter and pagination 'always' even if there are not records, that would solve my issue, or add the pagination dinamically when I reach more than 10 results.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there ant reason why you can't use `sAjaxSource` to populate the datatable?

Comment: Did you define 'aLengthMenu'? Does the first value of this array happen to be '10'? Check if the datatable registry info goes past the value 10 ...